# rand() functions producing pseudo-random numbers in [0,1] range

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods, random

Reading the Wikipedia I stumbled at the [List of random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators).

It seems that all the effort in developing PRNGs went into generating uniform integers in some given range, let call it $[0, N]$.

If i want to get a "real" number in range $[0, 1]$, by using function rand() (e.g. in MATLAB), I internally generate an integer number in the above range $[0, N]$. Then the generated number is scaled down by $N$.

What makes me wonder, is that representable floating-point numbers (I suppose) are not uniformly dense in $[0, 1]$, i.e. I would expect that density  of representable floating-point numbers is a decreasing function on $[0, \infty)$

> Does this mean, that *scaling down* does not produce real numbers
>   uniformly distributed in $[0, 1]$ ?

E.g., let say $\frac{1}{N}$ is exactly representable number, but $\frac{1,000,000}{N}$ is not, but there is a pretty close number $\frac{1,000,000}{N} - \varepsilon$ - so it will be picked by the scalling down process.

Comment: I think the fact that there are so many more small floating points than floating points between for example $\frac12$ and $1$ should not make a big difference

Comment: You need to distinguish between "real" numbers and floating-pont numbers. In any case, scaling down produces only $N+1$ distinct real numbers. This is not uniform real numbers in $[0,1]$. It also does not give uniform floating-point numbers. For all practical purpose it is what you want.

Comment: @Somos, This is exactly my point. Are those floating-point numbers not uniformly distributed (even if they are discrete points)?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "uniform" doesn't it?

Comment: @Somos, though it took me a minute to understand what you are saying. My definition of "uniform" in application to the rand(), is that $\mathbb{P}(rand() \leq 1/3) = \frac{1}{3}$. Which could not be the case if $1/3$ is not representable exactly.